# How resolution of singularity is linked to continued fracton?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I vaguely recall that resolution of singularity may be linked to continued fracton, possibly it is cusp that links to CF. Could any one give concrete reference and give example? Thanks.

Comment: See also Hirzebruch, Hilbert modular surfaces. L'Ens. Math. 19, 183-281 (1973)

Comment: @user31415 thank you for your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linkage between singularities of algebraic varieties and continued fractions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126444/linkage-between-singularities-of-algebraic-varieties-and-continued-fractions)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler possible, I have just found they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussed in [John Voight's paper.](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/cfrac.pdf) The paper does not appear to be published, I know not why.

Comment: It looks like that the matrix from CF is similar to the representive matrix of the group